# Substituir pela mesma palavra pesquisada com o RegExr incluindo um novo caractere

Tags: regex, notepad++

tudo bem? Estou com uma dúvida. Utilizei a expressão (\d{2}.\d{2}) conforme imagem anexa para pesquisar os códigos desta lista de serviços.

Gostaria de um auxílio para que o *Replace* ocorresse com a mesma palavra pesquisada acrescida do caractere **;** no início e fim.

Será de grande valia uma solução para este caso, irá me ajudar bastante (Questões profissionais).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque no campo "Substituir por" a expressão:

```
;$1;
```

O `$1` representa o grupo capturado e será adicionado os caracteres `;` antes e depois do que foi capturado.

Um exemplo usando JavaScript, mas que o notepad++ trata da mesma forma:

```js
var string = "humanos 04.19 bancos 12.34 e 13.6";
var re = new RegExp("(\\d{2}.\\d{2})", "g");
var resultado = string.replace(re , ";$1;");
console.log(resultado);
```